# Keychain is broken system-wide after tampering with System.keychain

Tags: macos, password, unix, keychain

After some frustrations with a half-broken `login` keychain, I eventually found myself deleting `System.keychain` and hoping that it would regenerate with defaults. This was a terrible move in hindsight — now my Keychain is fully broken!

To give some examples of broken behavior, I needed to log into iCloud each time after several reboots (seems to not be the case now), and applications are having a hard time interacting with Keychain. Chrome doesn't seem to be able to store any passwords anymore.

Can someone please let me know what steps to take next? I have considered three things:

1. Fresh install of macOS
2. Using Unix/BSD skills and the `security` command to diagnose/repair everything
3. Just living with the current macOS state

#2 sounds the most appealing to me. I'm willing to read up on the design of Keychain, so if anyone has any reading material, feel free to drop it below.